# How can I select the same number of records from two different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select the same number of records from two different tables in SQL Server?

For example, I have a table A with 10 records and table B with 15 records; how can I select 10 records from A and 10 records from B ?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: This smells a lot like an [X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question. What is it you are really trying to do?

Comment: I am using MSSQL Server 2012

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If both the tables have same number and type of columns. Then use union or union all

```
Select col1,col2,col3 from table1
union
Select col1,col2,col3 from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
    SELECT col1,col2,col3
    FROM TABLE_A

    UNION 

    SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A) col1,col2,col3
    FROM TABLE_B
```